# Any tips how to increase editing speed on Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, 4k, performance, full-hd

I'm using old notebook, which has a bit trouble with editing fottage highier than fullhd.

Is there any approach, how I can, for example work with small files first and than final export will process originals ?

I don't mind longer final render as long as I can do the edits, cuts, colors, effects smoothly without lagging.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Cinegy Daniel2 codec for editing in Premiere Pro. This codec take more space on disk, but work veeeeery fast compare to H264. Also it work more fast for me compare to ProRes.

Cinegy Daniel2 can be replaced with DNxHD MXF OP1a or MXF OP1a. Try these codecs. In Premiere it works very good.

You can convert all your raw files to one of this codecs before work, and then you will have more smooth workflow.
With this codec I could edit multicam 4K video with more than 3 cameras and it worked smoothly.
I have i7-4770K, 24gb RAM and GTX970 GPU. It's a PC from 2013 year (approx).

Also you can convert your videos to lower resolution and link them in Premiere Pro as Proxy files. Then you will edit files with proxy preview, but when you will render them, Premiere will use original full resolution files. When you need you can switch in one click between proxy and original resolution files.

[image]

For better understanding you can goole "Premiere work with Proxy files", "Premiere Cinegy Daniel 2", "Editing codecs for Adobe Premiere".
I can't google for you, because I will have most of materials in Russian.

[Link to Cinegy Daniel 2 codec.](https://www.daniel2.com/)

Comment: Wow, this looks epic! /// so, I've installed the codec. In Premiere Pro I already have Export option to Daniel2 codec. 
However, how I can work with these files ? Are you first encode all your raw videos to Daniel2 and than work with it ? if so, what's the best approach ? Thank you

Comment: Hi. Yes, I put all my video files to Media Encoder and convert them to Cinegy Daniel 2. Then just add this converted files into the Premiere project and work with them.
Sometimes I add them as proxy files. Sometime if I have project with added files and some editing, I've just make offline all files and then relink new .mxf files.
Usually I need to do batch renaming of all Cinegy files, because Media Encoder add "_1" to the end of the files.
You can rename them before export or disable this option in Media Encoder, before adding files for converting.

Comment: Thank you! This is so useful! --- Could you explain me better why are you still using proxies ? I mean, if you just convert them all, isn't easier just to work with them directly ? --- I've also noticed that once I play .mxf file in Cinegy player, it has way more flat look than original file, once I do side by side comparasion. If I compare them in Premiere Pro, they look the same. Have you noticed that ? I'm asking because that could be the answer why you might still use .mxf proxies but exporting with originals. Thank you once more!

Comment: I use Cinegy Daniel as proxies, probably, because after editing video I need to leave all files on my PC. And in that way I can simply delete all converted material, but leave original files on my HDD. And in this case I don't need to do any relinking.
So, I use Cinegy Daniel only for editing period (it can be 1-2 days, week, month), then, after I've done final render, I delete all Cinegy files, but leave original, more small files for archive.
I didn't open videos in Cinegy Player for comparsion.You can try to change settings of converting and see on result.
You're welcome! :)